# What happens when I multiprocessing.pool.apply_async more times than I have processors

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.3, asynchronous

I have the following setup:

```
results = [f(args) for _ in range(10**3)]
```

But, `f(args)` takes a long time to compute. So I'd like to throw multiprocessing at it. I would like to do so by doing:

```
pool = mp.pool(mp.cpu_count() -1) # mp.cpu_count() -> 8
results = [pool.apply_async(f, args) for _ in range(10**3)]
```

Clearly, I don't have 1000 processors on my computer, so my concern:
Does the above call result in 1000 processes simultaneously competing for CPU time or 7 processes running simultaneously, iteratively computing the next `f(args)` when the previous call finishes?

I suppose I could do something like `pool.async_map(f, (args for _ in range(10**3)))` to get the same results, but the purpose of this post is to understand the behavior of `pool.apply_async`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll never have more processes running than there are workers in your pool (in your case `mp.cpu_count() - 1`. If you call `apply_async` and all the workers are busy, the task will be queued and executed as soon as a worker frees up. You can see this with a simple test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(chunk):
    print('working')
    time.sleep(10)
    return

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(2)  # Only two workers
    for n in range(0, 8):
        pool.apply_async(worker, (n,))
        print("called it")
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is like this:

```
called it
called it
called it
called it
called it
called it
called it
called it
working
working
<delay>
working
working
<delay>
working 
working
<delay>
working
working
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the code above and the the script only printed 8 "called it" then stopped. What would be the reason for that? I am using python 2.7.

Comment: @qkhhly I'm extremely late on this, but there was a bug in the example code (Using `n` as the parameter to `apply_async` when it should have been `(n,)`). Just fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

The number of worker processes is wholly controlled by the argument to `mp.pool()`.  So if `mp.cpu_count()` returns 8 on your box, 7 worker processes will be created.

All `pool` methods (`apply_async()` among them) then use no more than that many worker processes.  Under the covers, arguments are pickled in the main program and sent over an inter-process pipe to worker processes.  This hidden machinery effectively creates a work queue, off of which the fixed number of worker processes pull descriptions of work to do (function name + arguments).

Other than that, it's all just magic ;-)